# bootstrap multi select buttons and on('click')

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I want to use Bootstrap 4 buttons to indicate user choices on a page.   The buttons should toggle selected/unselected and I'll need to be able to read their state as they're changed.   I'm using on('click') to collect the state of the buttons.   The results seem like I've got a timing issue.  When a button is clicked it accurately reports the settings of all the buttons except the one clicked.   A separate button setup just to report the button states always reports correctly.   How do I correctly acquire the button states when one of the buttons have been pressed?

```
function showSelection() {
    jQuery("#selection_display").empty();
    jQuery("#selection_display").append("<hr>choice1  active:" + jQuery("#choice1").hasClass('active'));
    jQuery("#selection_display").append("<hr>choice2  active:" + jQuery("#choice2").hasClass('active'));
    jQuery("#selection_display").append("<hr>choice3  active:" + jQuery("#choice3").hasClass('active'));
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery(".option_group1").on("click", function () {
     showSelection();
  });
});
<button id="choice1" data-toggle="button" class="btn btn-secondary  option_group1">choice1</button>
<button id="choice2" data-toggle="button" class="btn btn-secondary  option_group1">choice2</button>
<button id="choice3" data-toggle="button" class="btn btn-secondary  option_group1">choice3</button>
<button onclick="showSelection();">Update Selection</button>
<div id="selection_display">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/johnnyruin/peo81svu/35/

Answer (score 1):

This is because the bootstrap `click` event was executed after your `click` event, the classes of those buttons haven't been updated yet.

You can update the classes by yourself, to get it shown in your indicators correctly, and turn it back to let `bootstrap` handle it:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery(".option_group1").on("click", function () {
     // update the class manually, to get it shown correctly
     jQuery(this).toggleClass('active')
     showSelection();
     // turn it back to let bootstrap handle it
     jQuery(this).toggleClass('active')
  });

});
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/erqm4avj/

---

Here I am adding another solution using Bootstrap's API:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery(".option_group1").on("click", function (e) {
     // Stop bootstrap's event
     e.stopPropagation(); 
     // Change the state manully
     jQuery(this).button('toggle');
     
     // do whatever we want with the right states
     showSelection();
  });
});
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ln9yrjpx/

Comment: Thanks Panwen, that does solve the problem.   I'd hoped there'd be a way to react to the click after bootstrap registers the click.   I'll go with your solution for now....

Comment: @JohnnyRuin See the other solution that I just added. `e.stopProgation()` stops bootstrap's click, and then we used bootstrap's API to mimic the click to change the state. Then we can do whatever we want that is planned to be done after bootstrap's click.